# Перехват обновления страницы в компоненте

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть компонент:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './style/style.css';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Result from './../result/result';
import {getResults} from './../../api/education-api';

class Results extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type === 1) {
            this.props.history.push('/login');
        }
    }

    state = {
        surname: false,
        name: false,
        patronymic: false,
        correctAnswers: false,
        allQuestions: false,
        results: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        getResults().then(this.resolveResults, this.rejectResults)
    }

    resolveResults = (response) => {
        this.setState({surname: response.user.surname});
        this.setState({name: response.user.name});
        this.setState({patronymic: response.user.patronymic});
        this.setState({correctAnswers: response.correctAnswers});
        this.setState({allQuestions: response.results.length});
        this.setState({results: response.results});
    };

    rejectResults = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/login');
    };

    logout = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/login');
    };

    topics = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/topics');
    };

    render() {
        const results = this.renderResults();
        return (
            <div className="global_result">
                <div className="results">
                    <div className="result_tasks">
                        {results}
                    </div>
                    <div className="result">
                        <div className="result_user_name">
                            <h2>{this.state.surname} {this.state.name} {this.state.patronymic}</h2></div>
                        <div className="result_correct_answer"><h2>Correct
                            answers: {this.state.correctAnswers} of {this.state.allQuestions}</h2></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="task_two_button">
                        <input onClick={this.logout} type="button" className="come_back" value="Come back to login"/>
                        <input onClick={this.topics} type="button" className="come_back" value="Come back to topics"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    renderResults = () => {
        const resultsArray = this.state.results;
        return resultsArray.length !== 0
            ? resultsArray.map((element, index) => <Result key={'result' + index} numberTask={index + 1} task={element.task} solution={element.solution} actualAnswer={element.actualAnswer} />)
            : ('');
    };

}

export default withRouter(Results);
```

В конструкторе у меня есть проверка на обновление страницы..есть две проблемы:

1) после push у этого компонента все равно вызывается componentDidMount, как этого избежать?

2) когда проходит обновление страницы, он действительно выкидывает на логинку, но после на страницу с результами я больше не могу зайти, так как условие всегда уже будет правдиво, как это решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советов по улучшению кода Вам уже написали, касательно про объекдинение `setState` в один вызов, прям в глаза бросается. А теперь к делу, раньше можно было заюзать вот такую конструкцию кода, для определения, была ли страница перезагружена (положить прямо в конструктор, либо выделить в метод и вызвать в конструкторе):

```
if (window.performance) {
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    alert( "This page is reloaded" );
  } else {
    alert( "This page is not reloaded");
  }
}
```

Ссылка на источники:

- [React | How to detect Page Refresh (F5)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50026758/5275890)
- [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36444134/5275890)

Но если почитать немного документацию по используемому функционалу:

- [`Window.performance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/performance)
- [`Performance.navigation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation) [deprecated]
- [`PerformanceNavigation.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type) [deprecated]

То обнаруживается, что `Performance.navigation` и `PerformanceNavigation.type` являются устаревшими. Что же предлагается использовать взамен устаревшему функционалу:

- [`PerformanceNavigationTiming`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming)
- [`PerformanceNavigationTiming.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type)

Думаю, не составит большого труда переписать устаревший кода на рекомендованный функционал следующим образом:

```
var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
if (perfEntries && perfEntries.length > 0) {
  if (perfEntries[0].type === 'reload') {
    alert( "This page is reloaded" );
  } else {
    alert( "This page is not reloaded");
  }
}
```

Есть ответ на enSO в котором приведен пример кода из источника: [Example: `PerformanceNavigationTiming.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type#Example) собственно сам код:

```
function print_nav_timing_data() {
  // Use getEntriesByType() to just get the "navigation" events
  var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");

  for (var i=0; i < perfEntries.length; i++) {
    console.log("= Navigation entry[" + i + "]");
    var p = perfEntries[i];
    // dom Properties
    console.log("DOM content loaded = " + (p.domContentLoadedEventEnd - p.domContentLoadedEventStart));
    console.log("DOM complete = " + p.domComplete);
    console.log("DOM interactive = " + p.interactive);

    // document load and unload time
    console.log("document load = " + (p.loadEventEnd - p.loadEventStart));
    console.log("document unload = " + (p.unloadEventEnd - p.unloadEventStart));

    // other properties
    console.log("type = " + p.type);
    console.log("redirectCount = " + p.redirectCount);
  }
}
```

И ссылка на ответ: [New standard 2018, 2019 (PerformanceNavigationTiming)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53307588/5275890). Также, если для вас важно, чтобы этот функционал работал в конкретных браузерах, советую ознакомиться с [таблицей поддерживаемых браузеров](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type#Browser_compatibility) для `PerformanceNavigationTiming.type`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно, можно хранить состояние и в [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) и в [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), кому как удобнее, даже есть простой и понятный ответ с примером:

- [sessionStorage Check if page was reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17855311/5275890)

Comment: Да, учту все замечания, react только изучаю. В данный момент через sessionStorage и сделал. Просмотрю PerformanceNavigationTiming.type.
Спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте сделал какой нибудь компонент контейнер и вынес бы логику туда.

У вас все равно используется `react-router-dom`, сделайте что-нибудь наподобии:

```
<Container>
    <Route ... />
</Container>
```

И перенесите логику из своего конструктора в `componentDidMount` компонента `Container`. Тогда у вас не возникнет проблем и вы будете управлять своим роутом из этой компоненты.

PS:

1) Это работает? Это не `Duplicate declaration`?

```
import Result from './../result/result';
class Results extends Component {
```

2) Почему бы не объединить несколько `setState` в один? `React` конечно сам все сделает, но все же:)

```
resolveResults = (response) => {
    this.setState({
        surname: response.user.surname,
        name: response.user.name,
        patronymic: response.user.patronymic,
        correctAnswers: response.correctAnswers,
        allQuestions: response.results.length,
        results: response.results
    });
};
```

Comment: Я только изучаю react, setState исправлю...dublicate из-за того, что папка и файл называются по одинаковому. У меня так же есть главный App компонент, но не могу понять, как там отлавливать обновление(через f5) одной и той же страницы?

Comment: самое простое, это положить значение текущего URL куда нибудь в localStorage (так же его менять внутри localStorage при переходах) и тогда в  вашей компоненте App в componentDidMount сравнивать текущий URL с URL из localStorage, если они равны = нажатие f5